# Вставить "ма" после каждого слога в произвольном слове

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в задании. Мы вводим любое слово (например, литература) и нужно после каждого слога вставить "ма". Нужно использовать функцию strchr.Как я понял, нужно через цикл for находить каждую гласную и вставлять "ма" (возможно, через strncpy). Но у меня не получается реализовать это. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Код такой себе, но всё же:

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void main()

    {

        setlocale(0, "rus");

        char st[100] = "Лирика";
        char st1[100];
        char al[] = "АаОоЯяЕеИиУу";



        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(st); i++) {


            strncpy(st, st1, );
```

Не понимаю именно часть с strncpy, ибо он используется для копирования первых х символов. И возникает вопрос, как использовать его для вставки после гласных.

Comment: мы явно приближаемся к концу семестра

Comment: Да, только я это задание уже сдал.Мне сказали, что можно сделать ещё таким способом, а у меня не получается. Вот и интересуюсь. Это так плохо?

Comment: Напишите свое решение и уточните что именно не получается.

Comment: И как вы собираетесь находить границы слогов? Вот например в слове «здравствуйте».

Comment: @Elrion Это плохо тем, что "у меня не получается" без демонстрации Вашего кода создает впечатление попытки получить этот код.

Comment: @VladD 9   Думаю, что  стоит просто ориентироваться на гласные.  Т.е. вставлять "ма" после каждой гласной.

Comment: @Igor Я счел не нужным добавлять код, ибо застрял я почти в начале основной части, что  я и добавил в посте, отредактировав. Хотя соглашусь, что выглядит это, как "сделайте всё за меня".

Comment: @Elrion: Не, неправильно. Правильно будет «здрав-ствуй-те». Задача разделения на слоги очень тяжёлая.

Answer (score 0):

*Считаем, что задача разбиения на слоги решена (привет @VladD!).*

Установите указатель на начало строки с результатом `st1`. Установите другой указатель на начало `st`, находИте длину слога, начиная с этого указателя, копируйте соответствующее количество символов в результат, используя указатели в качестве параметров `strncpy`. Сдвигайте оба указателя на это количество символов. Копируйте "ма" в результат. Сдвигайте указатель результата еще на два символа.  Повторите.

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую сделать так.

Comment: Так нечестно, единственная интересная задача —так сразу «считаем, что решена» :)